# Good notation for many random points approximating an area.

Tags: soft-question, notation, random

I'm trying to say that as the number of random coordinate points points you plot approaches infinity, it is equivalent to an area integral where each point is an infinitesimally small $\mathrm{d}x \times \mathrm{d}y$ over the same interval.

The current expression I have is:
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} Pr[0 \leqslant RND(X_{n}) \leqslant 1, -1 \leqslant RND(Y_{n}) \leqslant 1] = \int\limits_{y=-1}^{1}~\int\limits_{x=0}^{1}\,\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$$

How could this be improved?